# User stories and defects in one grid

Tags: rally, appsdk2

I am trying to create a gird of user stories and defects together so that they can be properly prioritized by our product owner. I have tried using the 2.0 API to do this but have hit a wall. Looks like the Rally.ui.grid.Grid requires a single model but there are no model types that can be used to mix both User Stories and Defects together.

I tried using the getModels method but that only creates two distinct models and the grid doesn't like that. The grid requires only one model.

I have also tried creating my own model based on Artifacts but to register that with the ModelFactory I have to create a factory class which I don't know how to do.

Is there another way to do this given the 2.0 API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use use [Rally.data.wsapi.artifact.Store](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc2/doc/#!/api/Rally.data.wsapi.artifact.Store) instead of [Rally.data.wsapi.Store](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc2/doc/#!/api/Rally.data.wsapi.Store). See an  example in [this github repo](https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/completed-stories-with-no-changesets).

```
var myStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.artifact.Store',{
        models: ['User Story', 'Defect'],
        autoLoad:true,
        //...
});
```